# I would like to find some references about the demonstration of this theorem that the book doesn't cite anyone

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, partial-differential-equations

In Ambrosetti, A. and  Arcoya, D.,it An Introduction to Nonlinear Functional Analysis and Elliptic Problems there is a theorem that the autors doesn't prove and dont let any reference about it, the theorem is

Let,
\begin{equation}
\label{equ1.4.1}
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{lrl}
 -\Delta u  = \lambda m(x)u,&        &\,\, x\in \Omega\\
  \hspace{0.6cm}\, u  = 0,        &        &\,\,  x\in\partial\Omega
\end{array}
\right.
\end{equation}
Assume that $\Omega\subset{R^{N}} $ is bounded and open, $r\in \left( \frac{N}{2}, +\infty \right)\cap \left(1,+\infty \right)$, and $m\in L^{r}(\Omega)$. Consider the set
\begin{eqnarray*}
\Omega_{+} & = & \left\{ x\in\Omega ;, m(x) > 0 \right\}
\end{eqnarray*}
The following assertions hold.

- $0$ is not an eigenvalue of the equation above.
- If the Lebesgue measure $\left|\Omega_{+} \right|$ of  $\Omega_{+}$ is zero, then the equation has no positive eigenvalue.
- If $\left|\Omega_{+} \right| > 0$, then the positive eigenvalues of the equation above deﬁne a nondecreasing unbounded sequence  $\left\{ \lambda_{n} \right\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \subset (0, +\infty)$. In addition, $\lambda_{n}$ is characterized  by 
  $$ \frac{1}{\lambda_{n}} = \sup_{F\in \mathcal{F}_{n}}\inf\left\{ \displaystyle\int m(x)u^{2}(x)dx : \, \displaystyle\int \left|\nabla u(x)\right|^{2} = 1, \,\,\,\,u\in F \right\}  $$
  where\,  $ {\mathcal{F}}_{n} = \left\{ F\subset H:\, F\,\,\mbox{is a subspace with}\,\,\dim F = n \right\}. $

Has someone already seen this theorem proved anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

**Ad 1.** Eigenvalue $0$ would mean that there is a nonzero function $u$ for which 
\begin{equation}
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{lrl}
 -\Delta u  = 0&        &\,\, x\in \Omega,\\
  \hspace{0.6cm}\, u  = 0        &        &\,\,  x\in\partial\Omega.
\end{array}
\right.
\end{equation}
By the maximum principle for harmonic functions, such $u$ has to be zero.

**Ad 2.** You're not mentioning the space you're working in, but I assume it's $W^{1,2}(\Omega)$. By Sobolev embedding, we have $u \in L^{\frac{2n}{n-2}}$. The exponent $r$ is chosen so that the equation can be tested with $u$ itself (by Holder's inequality), resulting in 
$$
\int_\Omega |\nabla u|^2 = - \int_\Omega u \Delta u = \lambda \int_\Omega m u^2.
$$
The condition $|\Omega_+| = 0$ means $m \le 0$ a.e. in $\Omega$. If we assume that $\lambda \ge 0$, the RHS is nonpositive, while the LHS is nonnegative. Thus, $\nabla u \equiv 0$ in $\Omega$ and in consequence $u \equiv 0$.

**Ad 3.** This requires some more work and knowledge. Are you familiar with the case $m=1$, i.e. with the usual spectral theory for $-\Delta$?

Answer (score 0):

Chapter 4 of this thesis deals with eigenvalues for the weighted Laplacian. It has a few references, so it is a starting point.
[link](https://www.imsc.res.in/xmlui/bitstream/handle/123456789/262/TVAnoop.pdf?sequence=1)
This paper deals with the $p$-laplacian but again the references could be useful.
[link2](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.488.2935&rep=rep1&type=pdf)